# Sublime Text 2: Disable cursor position overwriting characters (like vim replace mode)

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm not sure how, but I managed to get Sublime Text into a 'Replace Mode' which at whatever position the cursor is at, it overwrites the next character with whatever you press instead of inserting it.

How do return back to 'Insert' mode?

I couldn't see any option for it in the menu and searching on Google yielded completely irrelevant results.

For the record, I'm using OS X Mountain Lion, and I have the non-extended keyboard (without the number pad).

Comment: Interesting, it only appears to be for that one document I was working on. Problem solved, but it would be useful to know how to enable and disable it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you go to `Preferences->Key Bindings (Default)` and search for "overwrite" you'll find the key binding. At least on Windows it's set to the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. You probably managed to hit some key combo to emulate that key on your keyboard. If it happens again and you can't figure out how to get out, just change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (unused in my default setup) and you should be good to go. Make sure that you put this entire line in your `Preferences->Key Bindings (User)` file, in between the square brackets:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+i"], "command": "toggle_overwrite" },
```

The `,` at the end is only needed if you have additional entries in the file.

Comment: Great. In my defaults this was super+alt+o which I believe translates to ctrl+alt+o on Windows.

Comment: @Adam-E - `super` is actually the `Command` key in OSX. I use Sublime both on Win and Mac, and sometimes `super` is changed to `ctrl` on Windows, and sometimes it isn't, which is a little frustrating. Luckily, most of my real work is on my Mac, which I love :)

Comment: Works in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: this was driving me crazy hehehe thank you!!

Answer (score 19):

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+o"], "command": "toggle_overwrite" }
```

This setting is present in Preferences -> Keybindings - Default

i.e. on Mac <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> works as insert.

Answer (score 1):

On the top row of a QWERTY keyboard there is a button marked  <kbd>INSERT</kbd>.  Simply tap that button.  It toggles between Insert mode and Overwrite mode.

Comment: However, on a non-extended keyboard, there is no insert key.

Answer (score 0):

That unsettling key seems to be the "0" in the number pad, on the right. Just press it again and you will shift back to insert mode (at least that's how it goes in my linux laptop)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).